# What is the best aproach to develop and implement a superclass/subclass ED diagram for these two entities?

Tags: sql, database, subclass, entity-relationship, superclass

I was wondering if someone could help me decide what is the best way to develop two simple database entities. I have come up with two ways but I can't see the obvious reason why one would be better than the other.

(there is a mistake in GroupMessage entity two, the attribute message appears twice)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided a lot of background information, but it is clear that there are shared attributes between FriendMessage and GroupMessage. There is probably additional commonality between the Sender and Creator attributes, and likewise for the Receiver and Group attributes. That makes the first a clear preference, if only based on DRY. I cannot think of a single reason or circumstance that would prefer the second, completley disjoint, representation.